# how to enable crypto in node js

Tags: node.js, hash, cryptography, node-crypto

I am including crypto module in node.js, but its methods are not accessible

```
var crypto = require("crypto");
exports.testSHA = function(req,res) {
    var shasum = crypto.createHash('sha1');
}
```

on createHash it says Unresolved function or method createHash().

Is there anything to include a module?

Comment: What does `crypto` contain post the `require` call?

Comment: yes it will post the call, but why I cannot see a method createHash() method?

Comment: That should work, crypto is built in to Node, and it has a createHash function, and even the variable names are right out of the manual, so something else must be wrong.

Comment: What if you run `node -v` in your console. What is the output.

Comment: So what does `crypto` contain if you run `console.debug(crypto)`?

Comment: console.debug in the code? if i write this line in the code it throws an exception TypeError: Object #<Console> has no method 'debug'

Comment: `console.debug` is not available in node.js "yet", your code snippet looks simple, and i don't see anything wrong with it. i executed this, and it didn't throw any errors, crypto, is in standard node.js installation. Try to open up, a simple node.js shell, and write `console.log(require('crypto').getHashes())` it should output a list of all available hashes , if not, then there is a problem somewhere else..